# Making Hive substitution variables avialable for all the sessions.?

Tags: hadoop, hive

If i have to make a substitution variable available for all the hive sessions in a Environment /Database which would be the best file to set it in? Is there a possiblilty to define my own config file and define the variables in it and it is available for all the queries?

Can i do it without using hive-site.xml and hive-default.xml?

Regards,
Nish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting your variables in .hiverc file.

You can add configuration or any custom variables in .hiverc file and Hive will load this file on launch of shell.

For eg : 
Add '**set tableName=test**;' in .hiverc file.
You can refer it in hive shell as '**select * from ${hiveconf:tableName}**'